# Which element has lost focus? [Windows Phone 7, Silverlight]

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

There is situation - one UI element gets focus. How to determine which element has lost its focus before that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no easy way. You will have to listen to the involved UIElements [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) Event.